# What is the benefit of a logical working directory?

Tags: symlink, cwd

I understand what a logical working directory is. When you create a symbolic link to a directory, and then `cd` to that directory using the symbolic link, your logical working directory becomes **the path of the symbolic link + the symbolic link itself**! for example:

```
$ pwd
/home/john/this_is_a_symbolic_link
```

But what is the benefit of a logical working directory exactly?

Comment: If you have a logical pwd, try each of the following: `cd ..`, `cd $(dirname $(pwd -L))`, and `cd $(dirname $(pwd -P))`.  Which of the latter two corresponds to the first?  In my case, replacing `cd` with `ls` could be confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A somewhat complicated use case:

On some system, users' home directories may, for example, be mounted by an *automounter* (as on Solaris).

From [the Wikipedia "Automounter" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automounter):

> The automounter has the purpose of conserving local system resources and of reducing the coupling between systems which share filesystems with a number of servers. For example, a large to mid-sized organization might have hundreds of file servers and thousands of workstations or other nodes accessing files from any number of those servers at any time. Usually, only a relatively small number of remote filesystems (exports) will be active on any given node at any given time. Deferring the mounting of such a filesystem until a process actually needs to access it reduces the need to track such mounts, increasing reliability, flexibility and performance.

The automounter may mount a `home` NFS share from some central fileserver under a path such as `/a` or `/tmp_mnt` or similar, and then create a symbolic link from `/tmp_mnt/home/steve` (the physical home directory) to `/home/steve` (the logical home directory) when you log in.

This has the benefit, as the Wikipedia article mentions, of only requiring one single mount of the `home` NFS share even if multiple users are active. When someone's home directory is no longer in use, the symbolic link may be removed, and when all users are logged out, the mounted NFS share may even be unmounted completely.

---

A more simple example:

Let's say you run out of space on `/usr/local`.  You may then add new disks and mount them as e.g. `/data/disk1` and `/data/disk2`.  Then you may decide to copy the old contents of `/usr/local/bin` to `/data/disk1` and `/usr/local/lib` to `/disk/data2` and recreate `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib` as symbolic links to these two directories.

Changing directory with `cd /usr/local/bin` would then physically move you to `/data/disk1` but logically you'd be in `/usr/local/bin`. This also has the effect that accessing utilities from `/usr/local/bin` would transparently access their physical location in `/data/disk1` without you having to update your `$PATH` variable.

---

Another one:

You may create a symbolic link from a user-mounted USB stick or other storage device somewhere under `/media` as `/home/steve/my_work_files`.  The benefit of this would be that you would be able to `cd` into `~/my_work_files` rather than having to remember where under `/media` your files are located.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cd this_is_a_symbolic_link
…
$ pwd
$ cd ..
```